# Typescript error when trying to repeat a component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I’m facing a TS problem and I can’t seem to find the answer on Stack Overflow. I’m trying to create a loop that’ll repeat a JSX component. The function is working perfectly but I can’t seem to figure out how to fix the typescript error

This is the error I’m getting -
Type ‘Element[]’ is missing the following properties from type ‘Element’: type, props, keyts(2739)

This is the code I have

```
if (condition1 || condition2) return [...Array(4)].map((index: number) => <RandomFunc key={index} />);
```

Comment: Show more code pls

Comment: Apparently, the function that this is inside of expects an `Element` to be returned, not an `Element[]`. Can you show us that surrounding function?

Comment: No, the function surrounding the line of code you shared. It might be a component, or it's a function with an explicit return type of `Element`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React components need to return a JSX element, not an array. You can wrap your array in a fragment to fix this:

```
if (condition1 || condition2) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {[...Array(4)].map((index: number) => <RandomFunc key={index} />)}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Or, using the fragment shorthand:

```
if (condition1 || condition2) {
  return (
    <>
      {[...Array(4)].map((index: number) => <RandomFunc key={index} />)}
    </>
  )
}
```

> The function is working perfectly

It's possible that react has checks to guard against someone returning an array and it ends up working correctly at runtime, but as far as the types are concerned, returning an array is not allowed.